# Using 'android update project' from command line w/ --library

Tags: android

I'm trying to use 'android update project' from the command line
with "--library".

I know that "--library" needs to use the relative path to the project.
I usually run a .bat file that CD's me into 'tools' so I can run 'android'
directly.

I've run this fine before, without using any "--library", but I haven't
had any luck with trying to use it with it.

My project directory is:  C:/Android/dev/SupportLibTest
and it has a 'libs' directory with 'android-support-v4.jar' in it.

I've tried to use many different versions of this:

```
android update project --target 10 --path c:/android/dev/SupportLibTest --library c:/android/dev/SupportLibTest/libs/android-support-v4.jar
```

yes, I know that it's currently using the full path for --library, and that it's wrong.

What should the relative path be for Windows and Linux or Mac?

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
Resolved location of library project to: c:\android\dev\SupportLibTest\libs\andr
oid-support-v4.jar
Error: Project folder 'c:\android\dev\SupportLibTest\libs\android-support-v4.jar
' is not a valid directory.
Error: No Android Manifest at: c:\android\dev\SupportLibTest\libs\android-suppor
t-v4.jar
```

If I need to fill-in some properties entries, I'm willing to do that.
How can I get it to work?

Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that relative paths do not work here. At least, it's been an on-and-off bug over time :/ Anyway I think `--library` is not needed for jars in the `libs` folder, only for library projects. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: I just need the 'android update project' to work so that I can do an Ant build on the project and that the Library stuff will work.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant: does `android update project` (without the `--library` option) cause errors?

Comment: I'm trying to build some of the Support samples, using  Eclipse, but so far no luck even with that, and I'm looking at the main Ant build.xml in the SDK..

Answer (score 2):

The `--library` switch for `android update project` is necessary only for library projects, not for jars in the `libs` folder. So you do not need to use it for `android-support-v4.jar`.

Preparing the support library samples for ant is a little trickier now, since they use multiple library projects. Try the following steps.

1. Copy the sample folder somewhere (e.g. `C:\Test\Support7Demos`).
2. Also copy the `appcompat`, `gridlayout` and `mediarouter` folders into `C:\Test`.
3. Move into the `appcompat` folder and run `android update project --path . --target android-19`
4. Move into the `gridlayout` folder and run the same command.
5. Move into the `mediarouter` folder and run `android update project --path . --target android-19 --library ..\appcompat`. This is necessary since the `mediarouter` project references the other one as a library.
6. Then, move into `Support7Demos` and run

   1. `android update project --path . --target android-19 --library ..\appcompat`
   2. `android update project --path . --target android-19 --library ..\gridlayout`
   3. `android update project --path . --target android-19 --library ..\mediarouter`
7. Finally, `ant release`. It should build without any errors.

An easier alternative would probably be to run `update project` on all and just edit their `project.properties` files manually. ;)

For example, it should look like this for `Support7Demos`:

```
# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=..\\appcompat
android.library.reference.2=..\\mediarouter
android.library.reference.3=..\\gridlayout
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I want to do more testing.

Comment: I tried to build the "easier" sample from Support13Demos.  Ran 'android update project --path c:\android\dev\Support13Demos --target 15'  but when I try to build the project with 'ant debug' get an error: 'FragmentTabsFragment.java:34: cannot find symbol 'method getChildFragmentManager()'  in:  'mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.pager);'  I added a 'libs' directory with the .jar in it , but I didn't add any 'android.library.reference' in project.properties.  If I need that, what's the proper way to use it?  Thanks

Comment: On second thought, I switched to try to build the sample for v4 as v13 has v4 embedded and that might cause issues.  Not having any luck building the v4 sample with Ant.